# Know when user "reads" a push notification from my app?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to get a callback or some other notice when a user has read or "seen" a push notification from my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a callback only if the user taps on the notification to open the app. In that case either `didReceiveRemoteNotification` (if app was active or in the background) or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (if app wasn't running) is called. In both of them you can access the dictionary containing the push notification data, and callback your server if you wish.